# express elegant way to restrict resources belongs to specific user

Tags: node.js, jwt, authorization

I found a lot of thread about permissions/role based authorization. however i'm looking for an elegant way or any bast practice to return data/resource belongs to specific user?

for example: I expect that http://localhost:3000/transactions will not return all transactions, only the transactions that belongs to the authenticated user that initiated the request.

my simple/manually solution? each transaction item has `user_id` field, so I can write middleware that decode the jwt token and takes the `user_id` from the token and expose it to the `request` object (i.e `request.user_id = user_id from the token`). and for each route (like transaction) i can take this `request.user_id` and add it to the query.

I wonder, what's is the best solution to handle this in express/node.js application? library? service? SaaS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds correct. UserID is a value used for authorization, received in a digitally verifiable way, and referred to as a [claim](https://curity.io/resources/learn/what-are-claims-and-how-they-are-used/). A good approach is to design a `claims` or `claimsPrincipal` object containing details like this, used by your API's business authorization.

In Node.js this is sometimes processed in middleware when the token is validated and then saved to `response.locals.claims`, as in  [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L24). The values can then be used by business logic as you describe.

Comment: Does this mean I need to attach userId (in this example) for each item in the DB?

Comment: That depends on data, but it is usual to do something like that. Business resources often have a User ID stored against them.